# Composite key with manual increment

Tags: mysql, database

How do I, in a multiple session / transaction environment, safely insert a row into a table containing a primary composite key with a (manual) increment key.

And how do I get hold of the latest incremented value of `column_c`, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` don't return the desired value.

I have looked into `SELECT FOR UPDATE ... INSERT` and `INSERT INTO SELECT` but can't decide on which to use.

What is the best way to achieve this in terms of transaction safety (lock), isolation level and performance standpoint.

**Update** - Another take on the problem

---

Lets say two transactions / sessions try to insert the same column_a, column_b pair (example 1,1) simultaneously. How do I;

1. Execute the insert queries in sequence. The first insert (transaction 1) should result in a composite key of 1,1,**1**, and the second (transaction 2) 1,1,**2**. I need some sort of locking mechanism
2. Retrieve the column_c value of the insert. I probably need to utilize variables?

---

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
        `column_a` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `column_b` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `column_c` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (column_a, column_b, column_c)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Exempel data**

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| column_a | column_b | column_c |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        1 |        2 |
|        1 |        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        1 |        3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

**Take on the insert into select query**

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`)
SELECT 2,1, IFNULL(MAX(`column_c`), 0) + 1 FROM `table` 
WHERE `column_a` = 2 and `column_b` = 1;
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO...SELECT` should be atomic, i.e. it should succeed or fail, at least for InnoDB.  What is the exact problem?

Comment: Lets say two transactions / session try to insert the same column_a, column_b pair (example 1,1) simultaneously. How do I;

1. Execute the insert queries in sequence. The first insert (transaction 1) will result in a composite key of 1,1,1, and the second (transaction 2) 1,1,1. I need some sort of locking mechanism

2. Retrieve the column_c value of the insert.

Comment: Perhaps consider adding a new primary key field that has an autoincrement. Then folks do their inserts, you get the `last_insert_id` based on that autoincrement primary key and then retrieve your `column_c` value. Anything else you attempt is going to cause all sorts of headaches. Since there is no such thing as a simultaneous insert you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Does it have to be a pure SQL solution? I've solved this exact problem by using code, not sure if it can be 100% solved in just SQL.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SET ... column_c = LAST_INSERT_ID(column_c+1) WHERE ... ` doesn't work? Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but I think that works for a problem I have which is similar.

Comment: Apologies, that works fine for UPDATE but not for INSERT. Interesting problem.

Comment: The 'best' way, is to not do it at all. And instead use InnoDB's own auto-incrementing  feature to maintain data integrity. If you really need these sub-values, you can always derive them on-the-fly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT @c := MAX(c) + 1
    FROM t
    WHERE a = ? AND b = ?
    FOR UPDATE;           -- important
if row found              -- in application code (or Stored Proc)
then
    INSERT INTO t (a,b,c)
        VALUES
        (?, ?, @c);
else
    INSERT INTO t (a,b,c)
        VALUES
        (?, ?, 1);
COMMIT;
```

The hope is that the `FOR UPDATE` will stall until it can get a lock and the desired `c` value.  Then the rest of the transaction should go smoothly.

I don't think that the setting of `transaction_isolation` matters, but that is worth studying.

Comment: And what happens if "a" and "b" does not exist as of yet? (Entirely new composite key set). Will the lock have any effect at all? Will it lock the entire table?

Comment: Hmmm...   I updated my code, but I am not feeling confident in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stored procedure for this:

I never encountered this kind of issue and if I ever do, I would do as following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insert_when_duplicate`(val1 int, val2 int, val3 int)
BEGIN

     -- catch duplicate insert error
     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
     BEGIN
        -- we could recursively try to insert the same val1 and val2 but increasing val3 by 1
        call sp_insert_when_duplicate(val1,val2,val3+1);
     END;

     -- by default mysql recursive limit is 0, you could set as 10 or 100 as per your wish
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth=10;

     -- [Trying] to insert the values, if no duplicate this should continue and end the script.. if duplicate, above handler should catch and try to insert again with 1+ value for val3
    INSERT INTO `table` (`column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`) values (val1,val2,val3);


END
```

usage would be:

```
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,2,1);
select * from `table`;
```

result:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| column_a | column_b | column_c |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        1 |        2 |
|        1 |        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        2 |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

same applies within a transaction:

```
start transaction;
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(1,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,1,1);
call sp_insert_when_duplicate(2,2,1);
commit;

select * from `table`;


+----------+----------+----------+
| column_a | column_b | column_c |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        1 |        2 |
|        1 |        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        2 |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

**however I haven't tried parallel transactions!**

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the table containing these 3 columns as `ThreeColumnTable` to avoid confusion arising from the name of you have given - `table`.

It's the column `column_c` that's manually incremented. Pull it out and keep track of the last value used for this column in another table.

---

**Solution's steps:**

1. Create a table that stores the last value used for `column_c`. Let's call this table `LastUsedIdTable`. `LastUsedIdTable` will contain only three columns:

   - Name of table whose column you want to increment manually (Example: `ThreeColumnTable`);
   - Name of column itself (Example: `column_c`);
   - Last value used for that column (Example: `121`).
2. Now, for ease of use, write a Stored Procedure that performs a transaction on `LastUsedIdTable`. This proc will read the last value used for the `column_c` in your case. Increment it. Return the incremented value to you. (Of course, you can do a direct query too every time. Stored Procedure is a better choice.)
3. Now the returned value of `column_c` is frozen for you because the Stored Procedure has increment the value in `LastUsedIdTable` for the `ThreeColumnTable` row for good. Anyone who wants to add another row to the `ThreeColumnTable` will call the Stored Proc and get the non-conflicting and incremented value, even if you are not yet done with insertion of your previous value in your `table`.

---

**Demonstration of the solution's workability:**

To keep the demonstration generalized, consider that you have *n* simultaneous requests for insertion in `ThreeColumnTable`.

All the *n* requests will have to first call the Stored Procedure. Since the Stored Proc utilizes a transaction on the `LastUsedIdTable`, at a time only 1 request will be accessing the row for `ThreeColumnTable`, which currently looks like:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| ThreeColumnTable | column_c | 121 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Now, the first request will lock this row and get `122` as the value, and also update the value in the table's row to 122. By the time the *n* requests will be finished, the `LastUsedIdTable`'s `ThreeColumnTable` row will look like:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| ThreeColumnTable | column_c | (121 + n) |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Now, those *n* requests will already be on their way to perform the insertion in `ThreeColumnTable`. But since they all have their own unique values of `column_c`, their insertion will be free of conflict, irrespective of the order in which insertion happens! You may have the value `121 + n` inserted first and `122` inserted the last. In fact, you don't even need the `column_a, column_b, column_c` tuple to be unique because `column_c` will always be unique.

This solution works fine for parallel requests as well as serial ones. With only a very very minor (to the point of negligible) hit to performance, this would be the sweet point of transaction safety, isolation level and performance that you are trying to hit.

---

**Important:** *Use `LastUsedId` to store the last value of all such primary key columns in all the tables of your database. Since this table will contain only as many rows as the number of keys in all of your database that you want to increment manually, it will contain only a limited and fixed number of rows. This will be fast and race condition free.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dummy value for `column_c` to lock the combination `(column_a, column_b)` for other inserts, which especially makes sure it will be locked even if no row for that combination exists yet.

```
start transaction;

set @a = 1;
set @b = 1;

insert into `table` (column_a, column_b, column_c)
values (@a,@b,0)
on duplicate key update column_c = 0; -- , column_d = null, ...

select max(column_c) + 1 into @c
from `table` where column_a = @a and column_b = @b;

update `table` set column_c = @c
where column_a = @a and column_b = @b and column_c = 0;

select @c;

commit;
```

The first `insert` will lock the exact combination (`column_a, column_b)`, but it will not block other values, so you can insert other combinations while the first transaction is running.

It will work with any transaction level, because `select max()` will be correct (and correctly gap lock) even if another session would update rows of the same combination (other than the locked row with `column_c = 0`) after the first insert; but if you use `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `SERIALIZABLE`, the temporary value (with `column_c = 0`) will of course be shortly visible to other sessions. In case this bothers you, use a higher level (e.g. keep the default).

`@c` will, as required, contain your last id, `@a` and `@b` will be replaced by your values and don't need to be variables.

If you put that code in a stored procedure, keep in mind that MySQL doesn't support nested transactions, so it is always risky to start (and especially commit) a transaction in a procedure, so you should do the transaction handling outside of the procedure.

`on duplicate key` is only there to make it fool proof. If everything works fine, you don't need it, but it will ensure the code will work even if someone (manually) added an invalid row with `column_c = 0` and left it there. Or if, in case you put the code in a procedure, someone called it without starting a transaction first, and another session inserts that combination at the same time, this can result in a duplicate key error (for the `update`) and thus might result in a residual row with `column_c = 0` (which you could of course delete in an exception handler in your procedure). It might be of interest to get informed (by crying users) if such a situation occured, so you may want to remove `on duplicate key` (at least for testing).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

This should be atomic and appears to insert the correct values:

```
INSERT 
  INTO table_name (column_a, column_b, column_c)
SELECT 
    :column_a,
    :column_b,
    COALESCE((
       SELECT MAX(column_c) 
         FROM table_name
        WHERE column_a = :column_a
          AND column_b = :column_b          
    ),0) + 1;
```

Where `:column_a` and `:column_b` are your new values.

Unfortunately if you want to use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function it will only work with `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.

You could add a surrogate primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
     `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
     `column_a` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `column_b` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `column_c` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE INDEX (`column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And run the same `INSERT` query above. Now your `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will reference the newly inserted row.

If you do add a surrogate key, it may be worth reassessing whether `column_c` is still necessary.

---

**Option 2**

You may also be able to get around adding a surrogate key by using a user variable within a single connection/transaction/procedure:

```
INSERT 
  INTO table_name (column_a, column_b, column_c)
SELECT 
    :column_a,
    :column_b,
    @c := COALESCE((
       SELECT MAX(column_c) 
         FROM table_name
        WHERE column_a = :column_a
          AND column_b = :column_b          
    ),0) + 1;

SELECT @c;
```

---

**Option 3**

If this is the only place you insert or update these columns in your table you could do some manual name-based locking. Simulating record locks with `GET_LOCK()` within a single transaction.

Start a transaction.

Choose a specific name for the rows you want locking. e.g. `'insert_table_name_aaa_bbb'`. Where `'aaa'` is the value for column_a and `'bbb'` is the value for column_b.

Call `SELECT GET_LOCK('insert_table_name_aaa_bbb',30)` to lock the name `'insert_table_name_aaa_bbb'`.. it will return 1 and set the lock if the name becomes available, or return 0 if the lock is not available after 30 seconds (the second parameter is the timeout).

Do your `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries here.

Use `DO RELEASE_LOCK('insert_table_name_aaa_bbb')` when you are finished.

Commit the transaction.

Be aware; calling `GET_LOCK()` again in a transaction will release the previously set lock. Also, this named lock will only apply to this scenario or where the exact name is used. The lock only applies to the name!

[**`GET_LOCK()` docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)

Comment: Will option 1 and 2 really work? Nothing is stopping two or more transactions from retrieving the same value of column_c? No lock is applied?

Comment: I believe single inserts are atomic, so there is no problem with the insert. Option 1 uses a surrogate PK unique to every row, so when you run LAST_INSERT_ID() you get the specific row last inserted by that transaction. You can then use that to retrieve the row's column_c. It doesn't matter if another transaction inserts another row, because LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the other row's unique PK to that transaction.

Comment: Option 2 works because user variables are session specific. Each transaction should be on a separate session and as each `@c` is set during the atomic insert, each session's `@c` should be correct for the row they inserted.

Comment: Personally, I don't think adding a surrogate is something you need to 'get around'. It just seems like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If data integrity matters to you, then consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,m CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,n CHAR(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO my_table (m,n) VALUES 
('a','b'),
('a','b'),
('a','c'),
('a','b'),
('j','p'),
('j','b'),
('j','p'),
('a','c');

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) i
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.m = x.m
   AND y.n = x.n
   AND y.id <= x.id
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
 ORDER
    BY m,n,i;

+----+---+---+---+
| id | m | n | i |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | a | b | 1 |
|  2 | a | b | 2 |
|  4 | a | b | 3 |
|  3 | a | c | 1 |
|  8 | a | c | 2 |
|  6 | j | b | 1 |
|  5 | j | p | 1 |
|  7 | j | p | 2 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

This design assumes no deletions - or deletions under only very specific circumstances

OTOH, if data integrity doesn't matter then consider whether a relational database is the right thing for your needs.